# Html.DropDownListFor set selected value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I create a @Html.DropDownListFor and populate it from the database. How can I set a selected value to the drop down?

My View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Forms, new SelectList(Model.Forms, "FormsCreatorID", "FormName"),
            "Select a Form", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

My Controller:

```
var forms = db.formscreators.Where(fp => fp.PropertyID == id || fp.PropertyID == 0)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.PropertyID).GroupBy(x => x.FormName).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
var viewModel = new ListFormsCreator { Forms = forms };
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class ListFormsCreator
{
    public List<formscreator> Forms { get; set; }
}
```

My Database Model:

```
public partial class formscreator
{
    public int FormsCreatorID { get; set; }
    public string FormName { get; set; }
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add another property to your view model for the store/pass the selected option.

```
public class ListFormsCreator
{
    public int SelectedFormId  { set;get;}
    public List<formscreator> Forms { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your GET action, you can set that value

```
var viewModel = new ListFormsCreator() { Forms = forms };
viewModel.SelectedFormId  = 2 ; // This will select the option with 2 as FormsCreatorID
return View(viewModel);
```

And in the view use the lambda expression with that property as the first parameter of the `DropDownListFor` helper method.

```
@model ListFormsCreator

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedFormId  , 
                         new SelectList(Model.Forms, "FormsCreatorID", "FormName"),
                        "Select a Form", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The `DropDownListFor` helper method will use the value of `SelectedFormId` property and select the option which has the same `value` attribute value from the list of options of that SELECT element.

You can also remove the dependency on `formscreator` class from the view model, by replacing it with a list of `SelectListItem`

```
public class ListFormsCreator
{
    public int SelectedFormId  { set;get;}
    public List<SelectListItem> Forms { get; set; }
}
```

Now in your GET action, you can use the `Select` method to generate the lsit of `SelectListItem` from your other collection.

```
var viewModel = new ListFormsCreator();
viewModel.Forms = someCollection.Select(a=>new SelectListItem { 
                                           Value=a.FormsCreatorId.ToString(), 
                                           Text=a.FormName})
                 .ToList();
viewModel.SelectedFormId  = 2 ; // This will select the option with 2 as FormsCreatorID
return View(viewModel);
```

Assuming `someCollection` is a collection of `formscreator` objects
Now in the view code is much simpler

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedFormId, Model.Forms ,"Select a Form")
```

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Conform with C#/.NET naming conventions:

   1. Rename `formscreator` to `FormsCreator`
   2. Replace `ID` with `Id` (as it's an abbreviation, not an initialism)
   3. Rename `ListFormsCreator` to something like `ListFormsCreatorViewModel` so it's obvious it's a ViewModel type and not a Model/Entity type.
2. Modify your ViewModel to add a property to store the selected `FormsCreatorId` value:

   ```
   public class ListFormsCreatorViewModel
   {
       [Required] // add or remove the 'Required' attribute as necessary
       public int? SelectedFormsCreatorId { get; set; }

       ...
   }
   ```
3. Set the `SelectedFormsCreatorId` property value in your controller action if necessary if you know what the value should be.
4. In your `POST` handler, ensure the `SelectedFormsCreatorId` value is maintained, either by directly passing-through the `model` action parameter back through the `View(Object viewModel)` method or manually repopulating it.
5. The view-model property in `DropDownListFor` should be the `SelectedFormsCreatorId` property. You do not need `new SelectList(...)`

   ```
   @Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.SelectedFormsCreatorId, this.Model.Forms );
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Update your viewModel and add an Int SelectId for the dropdown selected value.

In your controller:

```
var viewModel = new ListFormsCreator { SelectId = PropertyId, Forms = FormSelectList(forms, PropertyId.ToString()) };
```

I would create a function passing in a list:

```
    public static SelectList FormSelectList(IEnumerable<formscreators> types, string selected = null)
    {
        return new SelectList(from f in forms
                              select new SelectListItem
                              {
                                  Text = f.FormName,
                                  Value = f.FormsCreatorID.ToString()
                              }, "Value", "Text", selected);

    }
```

And in your .cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PropertyId, Model.forms, "Select a Form", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You should generate a 'SelectListItem' list on the controller with setting 'Selected' value and pass it via ViewBag or ViewModel. In my sample, for simplicity, I used ViewBag.
Here is the shortened Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    Album album = context.Albums.Find(id);

    if (album == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.GenreId = context.Genres.Select(
        g => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = g.GenreId.ToString(),
            Text = g.Name,
            Selected = g.GenreId == album.GenreId ? true : false
        }).ToList();

    return View(album);
}
```

Here is the shortened View Code

```
@using MvcMusicStore2017.Models;
@model Album
@Html.DropDownList("GenreId", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```